# Text file encoding to UTF_8?

Tags: java, text, encoding, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

I'm writing a Java project sending email with attachment. 


In my test case, I add some Japanese words "some Hiraganas and Katakanas" to my attached testfile.txt (which I saved in UTF-8 encoding.) 


But when I send my test email to myself, after I opened the attached testfile.txt, every Japanese Chars turns to be "????".

So I'm just wondering why this happens...?

Thank you

Allan

P.S. to be more specific, here is my code.
I am using mail.jar to send email.

Here is how I get the file:

```
/**
 * Add an attachment to the Email.
 * @param filePath
 */
public void setFile(String filePath){

    attachment = new File(filePath);

}
```

and below is how I attach the file into my MIME email part.

```
/*Add attachment if an attachment is given.*/
    if(attachment != null){
    MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    attachmentPart.attachFile(attachment);
    multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? How do you open the email/testfile? Can you post some code snippets?

Answer (score 6):

You need to ensure that you're reading and writing the file using the proper charset.

I.e. thus not so, which would use platform's default charset:

```
Reader reader = new FileReader("/testfile.txt");
// ...
```

But more so, using [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) wherein you explicitly specify the proper charset:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/testfile.txt"), "UTF-8");
// ...
```

Also, in the `Content-Type` header of the email attachment you have to set the charset attribute and you have to write out the attachment using UTF-8. Further detail can't be given as it's unclear what mail API you're using. Alternatively, you can also stick to using `InputStream`/`OutputStream` only as that would stream the content as pure bytes and thus wouldn't affect the charset the bytes represent.

---

**Update:** you're using Javamail's [`MimeBodyPart`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html) without explicitly specifying the content type with the charset attribute. Now you're dependent on the mail client whether it treats the content as UTF-8 or not. Fix it as follows:

```
MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
attachmentPart.attachFile(attachment);
attachmentPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=utf-8");
multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
```

Comment: This answer seems to work better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960556/javamail-attachment-from-string-encoding-problem

Comment: @mortensi: that answer workarounds (not solves!) an entirely different problem.

Comment: I tried to send an HTML-file (as attachment) with some Scandinavian characters within. I struggled for some time with it, and the above link solved the case for me.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/274480/java/java/JavaMail-set-content-utf) seems to address setting the characters set correctly for mime body content (last comment).