# Is it possible to set charset UTF8 for FileBody?

Tags: java, utf-8

I process a request which I then send to another endpoint. All work great except encoding for file name (it comes with corrupted characters if they are not typical).

I have figured out how to set UTF-8 for string items, however I do not know how to do that for FileBody class.

How can I set UTF-8 for file I send? Thanks!

I attached example of my Java code below

```
Map parameters = req.getParameterMap();

UploadedFile uploadedFile = (UploadedFile) parameters.get("file");

File serverFile = new File(uploadedFile.getServerFileName());
File clientFile = new File(serverFile.getParent() + java.io.File.separator + uploadedFile.getClientFileName());
serverFile.renameTo(clientFile);

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.addPart("file", new FileBody(clientFile));
builder.addTextBody("field1", "Načrt", ContentType.create("text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Comment: Check out the first answer here.. is it of any help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916674/text-file-encoding-to-utf-8
It says when you create the file you can create it with UTF-8

Comment: thanks a lot! it looks good, but I found another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all.

I found a solution for me case. See it beow.

```
Map parameters = req.getParameterMap();

UploadedFile uploadedFile = (UploadedFile) parameters.get("file");

File serverFile = new File(uploadedFile.getServerFileName());
File clientFile = new File(serverFile.getParent() + java.io.File.separator + uploadedFile.getClientFileName());
serverFile.renameTo(clientFile);

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

// fix <==========================
builder.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8")).setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

builder.addPart("file", new FileBody(clientFile));
builder.addTextBody("field1", "Načrt", ContentType.create("text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, you can change the entire encoding of all files handled by your program with this snippet of code at the start of your `main`:

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
Field charset = Charset.class.getDeclaredField("defaultCharset");
charset.setAccessible(true);
charset.set(null, null);
```

I had to use this for an app that had to read/write files in both Linux and Windows, which used some shady libraries to interact with the files.

Comment: thanks, I found another solution. I posted answer below.