# How to unit-test bidirectional text handling

Tags: java, android, unicode, junit, bidi

I am trying to write unit tests for some string-formatting code. Formatted output is likely in some cases to contain bidirectional text, i.e. a mixture of both left-to-right and right-to-left.

I have verified empirically that the output **looks** correct, for all combinations of LTR and RTL input and output, when run on an Android device or emulator. I am struggling to capture this in unit tests, though; I'm not sure how I can correctly specify, in my test cases, the expected output.

For example, I want to assert that the returned string will be rendered like this:

`-د.ك.123,456.78`

That is, the glyphs should appear in this order from left to right:

`-`

`1`

`2`

`3`

`,`

`4`

`5`

`6`

`.`

`7`

`8`

`.`

`ك`

`.`

`د`

<sup>(You have no idea how hard it was even editing that into the right sequence in the SO edit box!)</sup>

I have tried using standard string comparison methods in my test cases, like this:

```
assertEquals("-د.ك.123,456.78", formattedOutput);
```

but that fails because the expected-output string in the test code is having its text reordered. In fact it even appears differently in the source depending on which tool I use to view the source (Android Studio vs. Github-with-Chrome), so I have no confidence that it's testing the right thing.

I have also tried building up the expected-output value in steps, to avoid confusion in the editor, although it results in the same string literal being constructed under the hood:

```
assertEquals("-123,456.78" + SYMBOL, formattedOutput);
```

How can I compare the visual order of the glyphs, rather than the logical order? Will Android's `BidiFormatter` help me here?

Comment: Maybe this previous answer can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445133/string-utf8-encoding-issue

Comment: Can you show how you are building formattedOutput?

Comment: Also, can you show the output of the failed assertion? (i.e., show the value of formattedOutput that causes the assertion to fail)

Answer (score 0):

A typical `assertEquals` on that string and a method returning the same String (ie. a new String object) works fine for me, using IntelliJ 14.0.3 Ultimate, UTF-8 set for the actual text file.

What also works, and what you could try, is to get the bytes of the String you want to compare with (maybe manually specifying a specific encoding) and then compare the returned byte arrays with one another, using `assertArrayEquals`. I can't see why getting the bytes of a String using a manually set encoding wouldn't work, at least.

You could check this page for inspiration, if you like: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html