# JVM/AWT displays Unicode characters differently on different platforms

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, jvm, awt

I've been working on a little programming environment for Lisp-like languages. The environment can be run on JVM or on Android, and the JVM variant can be rendered to either Swing or terminal (using Lanterna library)

My editor is itself written in Kawa Scheme, and I plan, at some point, to start using it to edit itself - but so far, I've been mostly editing it from Emacs.

I can also render GRASP expressions to strings, which lets me write unit tests in a more visual way. Here are two examples of such tests, as displayed in Emacs:

[image: GRASP expression in Emacs in Terminal]

[image: GRASP lines in Emacs in Terminal]

When I open them in the terminal version of GRASP, they look fairly decent:

[image: GRASP expression in GRASP in Terminal]

[image: GRASP lines in GRASP in Terminal]

When I open them in the graphical version of GRASP under WSL, it looks like the font is missing some glyphs (I'm using Fira Mono):

[image: GRASP expression in GRASP AWT on WSL]

[image: GRASP lines in GRASP AWT on WSL]

But when I open the graphical version of GRASP under native Windows, it seems that the unicode characters are diplayed completely off the charts:

[image: GRASP expression in GRASP AWT on Windows]

[image: GRASP lines in GRASP AWT on Windows]

So the questions are the following:

1. How to force the JVM on Windows to choose the proper encoding?
2. Can anyone recommend a good looking monospaced font that would support a wide range of characters, including box drawing characters?

Comment: Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve]. Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code. Post a hexadecimal dump in case of (partially) binary content. Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. BTW, you face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'â–€â–€â–€â–„â–„â–„â–„â–– â–š â–Œ'.encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'utf-8')` returns `▀▀▀▄▄▄▄▖ ▚ ▌` (some character sequences estimated from the last picture)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [Mojibake in JavaFX (works fine in Netbeans)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567684/mojibake-in-javafx-works-fine-in-netbeans) I found that in order to make the program behave properly on Windows, one needs to pass `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` parameter to the `java` command (which solved the problem for me)